# Python - Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I am new  on Python. I am trying to use sklearn.cluster.
Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans

kmeans=MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(df)
```

But I get the following error:

```
     50             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     51         raise ValueError("Input contains NaN, infinity"
---> 52                          " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)

 ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')
```

I checked that the there is no Nan or infinity value. So there is only one option left. However, my data info tells me that all variables are float64, so I don't understand where the problem comes from.

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 362358 entries, 135 to 4747145
Data columns (total 8 columns):
User         362358 non-null float64
Hour         362352 non-null float64
Minute       362352 non-null float64
Day          362352 non-null float64
Month        362352 non-null float64
Year         362352 non-null float64
Latitude     362352 non-null float64
Longitude    362352 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(8)
memory usage: 24.9 MB
```

Thanks a lot,

Comment: `I checked that the there is no Nan or infinity value.` please show us how you did that.

Comment: Sort the data and check the top/bottom values.

Comment: I presume that `df` is a pandas DataFrame? If so, try `kmeans.fit(df.as_matrix())`. Scikit-learn has no concept of DataFrame, only of numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your `df.info()`, it appears that there are 6 more non-null Users values than there are values of any other column. This would indicate that you have 6 nulls in each of the other columns, and that is the reason for the error.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 362358 entries, 135 to 4747145
Data columns (total 8 columns):
User         362358 non-null float64
Hour         362352 non-null float64
Minute       362352 non-null float64
Day          362352 non-null float64
Month        362352 non-null float64
Year         362352 non-null float64
Latitude     362352 non-null float64
Longitude    362352 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(8)
memory usage: 24.9 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that [fit()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.fit) accepts only "array-like, shape = [n_samples, n_features]", not pandas dataframes. So try to pass the values of the dataframe into it as:

```
kmeans=MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(df.values)
```

Or shape them in order to run the function correctly. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Fabio, I tried this but I still have the same error

Comment: I am in the same situation. Verified that data does not have nulls but get the above error message

Answer (score 1):

> > > By looking at your df.info(), it appears that there are 6 more non-null Users values than there are values of any other column. This would indicate that you have 6 nulls in each of the other columns, and that is the reason for the error.

So you can slice your data to the right fit with iloc():

```
df = pd.read_csv(location1, encoding = "ISO-8859-1").iloc[2:20]

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 18 entries, 2 to 19
Data columns (total 6 columns):
zip_code     18 non-null int64
latitude     18 non-null float64
longitude    18 non-null float64
city         18 non-null object
state        18 non-null object
county       18 non-null object
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(3)
```